# Proper usage of Apache HttpClient and when to close it.

Tags: java, servlets, httpclient

I am using HttpClient within a servlet to make calls to a resource which I return as the servlets response after some manipulation.

My HttpClient uses PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.

I create the client like so:

```
private CloseableHttpClient getConfiguredHttpClient(){
    return HttpClientBuilder
        .create()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
        .setConnectionReuseStrategy(NoConnectionReuseStrategy.INSTANCE)
        .setConnectionManagerShared(true)
        .setConnectionManager(connManager)
        .build();
}
```

I use this client within a Try With Resource within the servlets service method, so it is auto closed. To stop the the connection manager from being closed, I set `setConnectionManagerShared` to true.

I have seen other code samples that do not close the HttpClient. Should I not be closing this resource?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For other versions of httpcomponents, see other answers.

For older versions of httpcomponents (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/quickstart.html):

You do not need to explicitly close the HttpClient, however, (you may be doing this already but worth noting) you should ensure that connections are released after method execution.

Edit: The ClientConnectionManager within the HttpClient is going to be responsible for maintaining the state of connections.

```
 GetMethod httpget = new GetMethod("http://www.url.com/");
  try {
    httpclient.executeMethod(httpget);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(httpget.getResponseBodyAsStream(), httpget.getResponseCharSet()); 
    // consume the response entity and do something awesome
  } finally {
    httpget.releaseConnection();
  }
```

Comment: Does the EDIT imply that the code following it to release the connection is unnecessary?

Answer (score 10):

For httpcomponents version 4.5.x:

I found that you really need to close the resource as shown in the documentation: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/quickstart.html

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://targethost/homepage");
CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

try {
    System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());
    HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
    EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
} finally {
    response1.close();
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you close the HttpClient too?

Comment: comments from the link page:
`The underlying HTTP connection is still held by the response object to allow the response content to be streamed directly from the network socket.
In order to ensure correct deallocation of system resources, the user MUST call CloseableHttpResponse#close() from a finally clause. Please note that if response content is not fully consumed the underlying connection cannot be safely re-used and will be shut down and discarded by the connection manager. `

Comment: @FernandoCosta If you are using only one instance of CloseableHttpClient in your application, it is recommended to not close it each time after a request, unless the the instanceof  CloseableHttpClient is no longer needed and is about to go out of scope the connection manager associated with it