# Strange issue with Apache Http Client Response

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've a strange issue while using apache httpclient.
I'm trying to consume another api by using the following operation

```
try{
    httpClient.execute(....)
}finally{
    HttpClientUtils.closeQuietly(response);
    HttpClientUtils.closeQuietly(httpClient);
}
```

The first time I deploy it on the server and execute it , it goes fine without any issue. 
However ,every next time I tried executing it, it always throws IllegalStateException connection pool is shut down.

Comment: Well, if you close the client, isn't it expected that you can't use it anymore after?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper usage of Apache HttpClient and when to close it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454514/proper-usage-of-apache-httpclient-and-when-to-close-it)